# Mock a bean and test injecting it into another bean's parameter

Tags: java, spring

I have a configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class AwsConfiguration {
  @Bean
  @Lazy
  public AwsCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider(final AwsCredentialsProperties credentialsProperties) {
    if(credentialsProperties.getProfilePath() == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("No profile path specified.");
    }

    ...
  }
}
```

And a test class:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = {
        AwsConfiguration.class
    },
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE
)
final class AwsConfigurationTests {

  @Mock
  private AwsCredentialsProperties credentialsProperties;

  @InjectMocks
  private AwsConfiguration awsConfiguration;

  @Test
  void profilePathIsNull() {
    when(credentialsProperties.getProfilePath()).thenReturn(null);

    assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> awsConfiguration.credentialsProvider(credentialsProperties), "No profile path specified.");
  }
```

The test works as expected. However, I want to remove the `@Lazy` annotation on the `credentialsProvider` bean. If I do, Spring attempts to instantiate the bean on test startup, which will obviously fail since there is no bean `credentialsProperties`. So, I remove `AwsConfiguration.class` from `classes` on `@SpringBootTest`. Then the test fails with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test`.

Seems I have a catch-22. How can I accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a SpringBootTest since it does not use any beans: it only uses a mock (`awsCredentialsProperties`) and a real class instance (`awsConfiguration`, *not* a bean!).

Since you are not using any beans or anything provided by Spring, remove the `@SpringBootTest` annotation and you should be good to go.

If you really want to have a SpringBootTest, then get rid of the mock instances and have the test register MockBeans and use the `awsConfiguration` bean from the application context:

```
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = AwsConfiguration.class,
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE
)
final class AwsConfigurationTests {

  @MockBean
  private AwsCredentialsProperties credentialsProperties;

  @Autowired
  private AwsConfiguration awsConfiguration;

  @Test
  void profilePathIsNull() {
    when(credentialsProperties.getProfilePath()).thenReturn(null);

    assertThrows(
        IllegalArgumentException.class,
        () -> awsConfiguration.credentialsProvider(credentialsProperties), "No profile path specified.");
  }
}
```